# I can't get the answer exactly

Tags: tcp, asp.net-core-mvc

Returning answer is too long, but I wait until I see how much my Thread.Sleep(). What should I do to see them all? instead of Thread.Sleep(100)

```
if (NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
    {
        TcpClient tcpCli = new TcpClient();
        bool connectionStatus = GetConnection(ipAddress, tcpPort, out tcpCli);
        NetworkStream stream = null;
        if (connectionStatus == false)
            return "Could not establish TCP connection";
        else
        {
            try
            {
                //Send data to TCP Client
                Byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(SendData);
                stream = tcpCli.GetStream();
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);


                //Thread.Sleep(100);


                //Read data from TCP Client
                data = new Byte[tcpCli.ReceiveBufferSize];
                Int32 bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                string answer = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);

                if (answer.Contains("**"))
                    return answer;
                else
                    return "Panel no answer";
            }
            catch (Exception) { return "COMMUNICATION ERROR"; }
            finally { tcpCli.Close(); }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please take a little more time to describe your problem. It is not really clear what you are trying to achieve here and what you actual problem is. The best bet for us currently is that you are trying to write and read to/from a TCP client stream in one process which seems a litte odd at best.

Comment: Maybe [Network Send and Reply](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/82742) can give you ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I solved it that way. maybe it could help someone.**

```
public static string TcpPanelGetSet(string ipAddress, int tcpPort, string SendData, string finishValue)
        {
            if (NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
            {
                TcpClient tcpCli = new TcpClient();
                bool connectionStatus = GetConnection(ipAddress, tcpPort, out tcpCli);
                NetworkStream stream = null;
                if (connectionStatus == false)
                    return "Could not establish TCP connection";
                else
                {
                    try
                    {
                        //Send data to TCP Client
                        Byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(SendData);
                        stream = tcpCli.GetStream();
                        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

                        //Read from TCP Client
                        string answer = "";
                        DateTime st = DateTime.Now;
                        DateTime et = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(300);
                        do
                        {
                            st = DateTime.Now;
                            if (st > et)
                                return "TIME-OUT";
                            data = new Byte[tcpCli.ReceiveBufferSize];
                            Int32 bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                            string tmpAnswer = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);
                            if (tmpAnswer.Contains(finishValue))
                            {
                                answer += tmpAnswer;
                                break;
                            }
                            answer += tmpAnswer;
                        } while (et > st);


                        if (answer.Contains("**"))
                            return answer;
                        else
                            return "Panel no answer";
                    }
                    catch (Exception) { return "COMMUNICATION ERROR"; }
                    finally { tcpCli.Close(); }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return "THERE IS NO CONNECTION";
            }
        }
```